# How to serialize enum as string globally (not by attribute in each enum)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm working on the ASP.NET Core 3.0 web API. A lot of endpoints return `json` with enums. Enums are not serialized as a string but as the default integer.

I'm aware of `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute. But I'm looking for a solution, where I would globally say "Every enum returned by this API should be serialized to `string`, without the need of manually declaring attributes in my model in each and every enum".

Until today, I worked with .NETCore2.1. I was able to achieve that with `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters` and this middleware:

```
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(op => { op.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());});
```

This code doesn't work in `.NETCore3.0`, so I'm looking for a solution that will globally convert enum to string, always, without changing or decorating my model classes in `NETCore3.0`.

Thanks for help

Comment: There is another good answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096102/asp-net-mvc-core-3-0-api-serialize-enums-to-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Core 3.0, the Newtonsoft.JSON package is no longer included by default.

Install the [following package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) and try to add the converter like this:

```
services.AddMvc(...).AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have `AddMvc()` anymore. In the bear API we should use `AddControllers()` now

Comment: @AdamWojnar The AddNewtonsoftJson() extension method should be available on there as well.