# ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

How to serialize Enum fields to String instead of an Int in ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0? I'm not able to do it the old way.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
{
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
})
```

I'm getting an error:

> cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter'
>   to 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter'

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.0 doesn't include JSON.NET which means you had to add the package explicitly before trying this code

Answer (score 203, accepted):

### New System.Text.Json serialization

ASP.NET MVC Core 3.0 uses built-in JSON serialization. Use `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter` (with "Json" prefix):

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    // Or .AddControllers(...)
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
    })
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#fast-built-in-json-support). The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).

### If you prefer Newtonsoft.Json

You can also use "traditional" Newtonsoft.Json serialization:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

And then:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => opts
        .Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

Comment: If you have a Web API then instead of `.AddMvc()` you can also use `services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(...)`.

Comment: as of asp.net core 3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.5, there is a slight change:
<pre>
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
</pre>

Comment: what if i dont want to do this accross the bard ? is there a way to do this as an attribute on my dto?

Comment: I found this website to be very helpful:  https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/2020/07/17/adding-newtonsoft-json-to-services

Comment: @drowhunter If you want to just do this or a specific property, you can simply annotate the property in the return DTO like this `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public CategoryDto Category { get; set; }`. You will need to import the `using System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespace

Comment: Thank you this worked for me `services.AddControllers()..AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    })`

Answer (score 28):

some addition:
if use **Newtonsoft.Json**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()));
```

options.SerializerSettings.Converters

`SerializerSettings` is necessary

Answer (score 23):

If you have a `Minimal API` this will be useful:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Answer (score 14):

.NET 7.0 introduces this way:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Aspnet Core MVC with the minimal API use this:

```
services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```