# Deserialization returns null properties (JsonSerializer)

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I know there is a lot of questions about this on SO but I still can't figure why this deserialization is not working. Maybe one more pair of eyes helps me with this.

I have this DTOs:

```
public class BasicDTO
{
   public OperatorEnum Operator {get;set;}
   public List<BasicChildrenDTO> Children {get;set;}
}

public class BasicChildrenDTO
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ChildOperatorEnum Operator {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have a windows form text box where I input a json and my methods is like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var str = textBox1.Text;

   var object = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BasicDTO>(str);
   //more Code
}
```

But when I debug my object it came with all properties as null and enums as default. But, deserializer recognize how many objects are in the list, so in my json put 1, 2 or x children object children length is 1, 2 or x (but with null properties).

I Tried the special paste with my json to look for any errors and this is the result

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string _operator { get; set; }
    public Children[] children { get; set; }
}

public class Children
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string _operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Any help?
Thank you

**EDIT**
This is my json code:

```
{
  "operator": "OR",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "operator": "EQUALS",
      "value": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "operator": "EQUALS",
      "value": "Bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how is received:

> "{\n  "operator": "OR",\n  "children": [\n    {\n      "name":
> "Foo",\n      "operator": "EQUALS",\n      "value": "Foo"\n
> },\n    {\n      "name": "Bar",\n      "operator": "EQUALS",\n
> "value": "Bar"\n    }\n  ]\n}"

I'm using System.Text.Json and I tried both with lower and capitalize first char but none of them worked.

**EDIT 2**

This question is already close and answered but I edit with my correct code for anyone helps. My two problems was that my deserializacion becames with null properties because the case-sensitive problem. Then I had problem with the deserialization of the enums.
So  my final code for that was:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var str = textBox1.Text;

   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
   {
      PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
      Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
   };

   var object = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BasicDTO>(str, options);

//more code
}
```

Comment: Can you an example of the json input you used?

Comment: Ah, wait a sec: Realize how the names are lowercase? Are you using NewtonSoft.JSON or System.Text.Json?

Comment: For System.Text.Json see [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0) and/or [How to enable case-insensitive property name matching with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing)

Comment: ^^ The System.Text.Json deserializer defaults to case-sensitive matching. The second link I posted above teaches you how to switch to case-insesitive matching. _I tried the special paste with my json to look for any errors"_ - that was an excellent idea!

Comment: You have to show your json that you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: Updated with my json

Comment: I tried your solutions Fildor but with case-insensitive enabled I get this error: The JSON value could not be converted to operator. Path: $.Operator | LineNumber: 1 |

Comment: As mentioned in comments above, System.Text.Json is case sensitive.  See [JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60123376/3744182) for a duplicate question + answers.

Comment: Regarding the new error *The JSON value could not be converted to operator. Path: $.Operator | LineNumber: 1*  this is likely occurring because you are now successfully trying to deserialize the `Operator` enum and so have exposed a second bug which had been hidden by the first.  This second issue is probably a duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59096102/3744182) but if not, please ask a second question with a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly use the JsonStringEnumConverter ? To tell the system search for strings not for intégral values

Comment: Finally it was the the two problems: case sensitive and deserialization of enums. So much thank you everyone!