# ENUM properties of Event's class failing to deserialize using latest Microsoft.Graph API version 5.*

Tags: c#, json, enums, microsoft-graph-api, system.text.json

I have a working version of application which uses Microsoft.Graph API version 4.37. Now upgrading it to use latest version 5.*.
The main updated/refactored code parts are working using dedicated request builders like:

```cs
var multipleEvents = (await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView.GetAsync()).Value;
var singleEvent = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events["Id of event"].GetAsync();
```

But there is a situation when I need to select different events by their IDs using Batch request. HttpRequests of type Get (by URL of event) are added to batch and  multiple response contents streams in version 4.* were parsed using:

```cs
var eventX = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<Event>(jsonFromResponceContent);
```

In version 5.* I'm receiving such json (shortened here):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('fb5b52e2-ce57-4273-875c-570a71c1c0d9')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "...........",
    "id": "id value here",
......................................................................................
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Dad's Birthday",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
          ........................................................
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "......"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "1991-05-24T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "1991-05-25T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
      .................................................
      ..........................................................
}
```

In version 5.* native HttpProvider nor any ISerializer no more exist or could not find where to instantiate them from. So decided to use

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
var event = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(jsonFromResponceContent, options);
```

But deserializer fails throwing "**The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.Graph.Models.Importance]. Path: $.importance ....**".

Deserializer does not fail only when all properties of type Enum or classes having enum subproperties are excluded using Select option, f.e. when URL of request is like

*https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/idOfEventHere?$select=id,iCalUId,subject,isAllDay,start,end,createdDateTime*

If I add "importance", "location" or "body" property to be fetched - deserialization fails on a first Enum type property.

Why it fails. What Serializer should I use?

**UPDATED:**
Suggestion of @dbc fixed all issues with Enum types.

```cs
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```

Related SINGLE remaining issue here: [Recurrence property of Event's class failing to deserialize using latest Microsoft.Graph API version 5.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242380/recurrence-properties-of-events-class-failing-to-deserialize-using-latest-micro)

**UPDATED_2:**
Here is the simplified code how Json is retrieved:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
               
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(GraphClient);
myBatchRequestSteps.ForEach(x => batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(x));
var batchResponseContent = await GraphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
var responces = await batchResponseContent.GetResponsesAsync();
foreach (var responce in responces.Values)
{
    var json = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var myEvent = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(json, options);
}
```

Comment: That being said, [`Microsoft.Graph.Models.Importance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/enums?view=graph-rest-1.0#importance-values) is an enumerated value, so if you are trying to deserialize a string value to an `enum` using System.Text.Json you must use [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter).  See [ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59096114/3744182).

Comment: Does adding `JsonStringEnumConverter` to `options.Converters` fix your problem?

Comment: thanks, @dbc, it helped (y), but partially. Now, when I added ',body,importance' properties to SELECT option they are being deserialized.

Comment: But if I remove SELECT option from url (give me all available properties) then it throws "System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Date. Path: $.recurrence.range.startDate" when recurrence property in json looks like 

"recurrence": {
  "pattern": {
                 .........
  },
  "range": {
   "type": "noEnd",
   "startDate": "1991-05-24",
   "endDate": "0001-01-01",
   "recurrenceTimeZone": "FLE Standard Time",
   "numberOfOccurrences": 0
  }
 }

Comment: I don't know anything about the graph API so I can't answer that.  The only thing I can answer is how to deserialize a string to an enum using System.Text.Json.  If that's not what you need to know, I'd suggest that you [edit] your question and narrow it down to what you do need to know.  The format for questions here is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so rather than asking one combined question, it's better to ask multiple simple questions.

Comment: Could you please share more code? How do you get jsonFromResponceContent ?

Comment: The solutions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242560/where-is-the-instance-of-iserializer-in-microsoft-graph-api-version-5/77244856#77244856