# Add a list of enum values to a query parameter

Tags: c#, rest, enums, query-string

For example you have this `enum` :

```
 public enum MyEnum
 {
     enum1,
     enum2,
     enum3,
     enum4
 }
```

And you want to pass a `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` as a query parameter?

I tried this :

```
 var queryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 var myEnums = someParemeters.MyEnums.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(nameof(MyEnum), x.ToString()));
```

queryParameters.Add(nameof(SomeParemeters.MyEnums), myEnums.ToString());

```
if (queryParameters != null) uri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, queryParameters);
```

But this doesn't work off course. How can I get the `MyEnums` as a string to send as query parameter '?myEnums=enum1&myEnums=enum4'?

PS : I'm using the library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`

Comment: Note that passing duplicate query parameters isn't supported by a lot of webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at following example:

```
public enum Season
{
    Spring = 1, 
    Summer = 2, 
    Fall = 3,
    Winter = 4
}

[HttpGet]
public string Get([FromQuery] Season[] seasons)
{
    return string.Join(", ", seasons.Select(s => s.ToString()));
}
```

you can simple call this method by:

```
https://[RestApiEndpoint]/WeatherForecast?seasons=1&seasons=2
```

If you gonna get these values as `Strings` not numeric literals you can read following question:

[ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096102/asp-net-mvc-core-api-serialize-enums-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop for each value of the enum and then join the elements using the character desired.

Something like this:

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).OfType<MyEnum>().Select(x => nameof(MyEnum) + "=" + x.ToString()).ToList();
string enumListStr = string.Join("&", enumList);
```

Hope it helps.